# Transform/Scale Pattern over X Axis using Shader Nodes

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I'm looking for a way to scale a pattern over the length of the X-axis using just shader nodes.
The bottom image is the effect I'm going for.
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just added those few nodes at the start of your tree and I thing that's what your trying to achieve. Here is what it gives me.

[image]
[image]